# Hook weekly newsletter with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, newsletter

I'm using MailPoet within my WordPress website and currently it's only optional for me to send a weekly newsletter (cron job or on user's entrance) based on categories only.

All my posts are tagged with different ACF fields as well, and I was wondering if it's somehow possible to 'hook' mailpoet's functionality based on chosen acf's and not only categories.

I dont have any code to provide but [MailPoet's GitHub repository link](https://github.com/mailpoet/mailpoet) page.

Comment: What is ACF field?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/